# Can't read file using nodejs fs module when file name is stored in environment variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, fs

I am running a node app in ubuntu server 16.04. I have set up an environment variable:

```
export FILE_PATH="file-path"
```

Then I tried to read the file in my node script:

```
const fs   = require('fs');
console.log(process.env.FILE_PATH); // gives correct path.
const data = fs.readFileSync((process.env.FILE_PATH || ""), 'utf8');
```

But I'm getting "no such file or directory" error in debugger. The file is existing and has required permissions. If I give the path directly instead of taking from env variable, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the root cause of this issue. All the environment variables I set has a ‘\r’ in the end.

console.log(process.env) gives the output:

```
...
FILE_PATH: '/tmp/file.txt\r',
...
```

As a quick fix I used trim() to remove the extra character:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync((process.env.FILE_PATH.trim() || ""), 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to parse your path with Node.js's [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module. Something like:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve((process.env.FILE_PATH || "")), 'utf8');
```

Comment: This gives another error ‘TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object’

Comment: Thanks @tbking. But "path.resolve" didn't resolved my issue. The env variable automatically adds up a "\r" at the end. I used trim() to remove it.